# UWP usb detection

Tags: c#, usb, uwp, detection

I would like to detect a USB drive in my app (on launch) but I can't find a simple way to do that!

In WinForms I used `DriveInfo` but it doesn't exist in UWP.

I found this:  [How to get notifications if devices are added, removed, or changed (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/li%20[...]%2067756.aspx) but it's not very simple at all! And it finds everything but my USB drive! (or it doesn't show it with the good name).

Can you help me please? Thanks

Comment: thanks you itsme86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this sample on [DeviceEnumerationAndPairing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing)

If you want this to be done when your app is open, then see Scenario 2

If you want this to be done when your app is not open ( background), then see Scenario 3.

In the sample, When i connected my USB, I was able to see the Device Interface ID and also the Name. This should help you get started.

**Edit 2**: So based on your requirement, See the documentation for [KnownFolders.Removable Devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows.storage.knownfolders.removabledevices)

This will give you all files and folders from a new added removable device (on phone with OTG or SD Card )

Comment: Thanks AVK Naidu. I've a problem with my PC so I'll try your suggestion as soon as possible and let you know

Comment: I tried the sample and the scenario 2 seems to be the best one for me. But i still have a question, how can i get the drive's letter to look Inside the usb device ? Or is it done in another way ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok. So from what i understand, First you want to detect USB Changes and if you found something, you want to query the files?

Comment: Yes. I need to find one USB drive and and read a file on it. But the USB drive's letter could change. So i need to find the path of my file dynamicaly with the ID of my USB Drive or with its name (for the name, I know that's not a good way to work).

Answer (score 0):

It will provide you all portalble device list

```
   var myDevices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceClass.PortableStorageDevice);
```

OR

```
 StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

 // An SD card is present and the sdCard variable now contains a reference to it.
    if (sdCard != null)
      {
        // do whatever you want!
       }
```